# Combining VLOOKUP AND IF in google spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a question on google sheets. See the table below for an example.

THE TASK IS: there are 2 tables: Table 1 and Table 2. Every time the Domain from Table 2 matches the domain from Table 1, I would like the record with matching domain in Table 1 to get “Y” in the column Result (Y/N).

The remaining mismatch domain records in Table 1, I would like them to get “N” in the column Result (Y/N) in Table 1.

This is what  I have so far, bur it does not show correct results.

=IF(VLOOKUP(E4,$A$3:$C$23, 2, 0),"Y","N")

Please help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use countif instead of vlookup.

```
=IF(COUNTIF(range,value),"Yes","No")
```

if using vlookup is a requirement, i suggest looking closely at what is returned from vlookup, my guess is that it isn't a value that can be evaluated by the if statement. countif returns a 1 if true, which the if statement will interpurt as true as well. googlesheets doesnt do "truthy" evaluations such as javascript. you could test for the successful return of the vlookup such as

`=IF(vlookup(...) == currently looked up value, "Yes", "No")`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Table 1 in columns A:C and table 2 in E:F and data starting in row 3, try in A3

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(B3:B), if(isnumber(match(B3:B, E3:E,0)), "Y", "N"),))
```

Change ranges to suit.